# How to make MongoDB update perform faster?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to import more than 200k records into mongodb. If data exists in db, we should update it else insert it. So I'm able to insert within 10 to 15 mins. But updating 200k records is taking more than 2 hours as I'm iterating over.

```
 For(){
   If(some validation){
     Var res = await getdatamongo();
      If(res.length > 1){

          Var ress = update(model,query,set)

     }
     Else{
         Insertdata.push(res1)

     }
   }
   }

 Bulkinstmongo(model,Insertdata);
```

how can I make update faster.

Comment: See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-upsert
Also insert multiple objects together, instead of going one by one.

Comment: @brahmaDev for each record, the values which I need to update is different..

Comment: In that case you'd better fetch all records, modify them and reinsert in bulk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What could help here is: [`BulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) [NodeJS driver Documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/tutorials/crud/#bulkwrite) which provides clients the ability to perform write operations in bulk. And if the order of operations does not matter an option `{ordered:false}` can be provided to improve the performance more.

Example:

```
const col = db.collection("collection_name");
let bulkWriteOps = [];
for (let i = 0, l = res.length; i < l; ++i) {

  const updateOp = {
    updateOne: { filter: { a: 2 }, update: { $set: { a: 5 } }, upsert: true },
  };

  bulkWriteOps.push(updateOp);
}

const result = await col.bulkWrite(bulkWriteOps, { ordered: false });
```

To have little more performance oriented approach in javascript (Nodejs) if the update or write ops size is very large is to use chunking and promises.

The idea is to chunk the ops in a defined size and send them to mongodb as soon as they come. And since the `BulkWite` op returns a promise, `Promise.all(..)` could be used to reach a stage where everthing is finished.

Example:

```
const col = db.collection("collection_name");
let bulkWriteOps = [];
let promises = [];
for (let i = 0, l = res.length; i < l; ++i) {

  const updateOp = {
    updateOne: { filter: { a: 2 }, update: { $set: { a: 5 } }, upsert: true },
  };
  bulkWriteOps.push(updateOp);

  /*chunking the operations into 10000 and sending them to mongodb*/
  if (bulkWriteOps.length === 10000) {
    const p = collection.bulkWrite(bulkWriteOps,{ ordered: false });
    promises.push(p);
    bulkWriteOps = [];
  }
}

/*sending the rest of left operations to mongodb*/
if (bulkWriteOps.length > 0) {
  const p = col.bulkWrite(bulkWriteOps,{ ordered: false });
  promises.push(p);
}

/*NOTE: Promise.all rejects if any of the promise by mongodb query rejects*/
try {
  await Promise.all(promises);
  /*everything finished*/
} catch (error) {
  console.error("one or more of the mongodb query operations rejected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `getdatamongo()` is doing a query on the database make sure that query is properly indexed. Otherwise as the dataset grows your query performance will decay.